# Mapfish Print v3 - Blank map

Tags: wms, mapfish

I'm using Mapfish Print **v3** to print a layer from the following link:

http://webapps.sit.puglia.it/arcgis/services/Background/TNOInquadramento/MapServer/WMSServer

To test the printing function I'm using the Test Print page shipped with the 3.3 shapshot.
Unfortunately any single attempt I've done so far has been unsuccessful: the pdf file produced always renders a blank map.

Still I can load all the layers into ArcGIS.
So I guess the problem must be on my Mapfish configuration/JSON request.

I tested my config.yaml and JSON request against the following link:

http://webapps.sit.puglia.it/arcgis/services/BaseMaps/Ortofoto2013/ImageServer/WMSServer

and it worked fine (although no matter the layers' names in the JSON request, I always got the correct result, anyway...).

This is my **config.yaml**:

```
templates:
  #===========================================================================
  A4 landscape: !template
  #===========================================================================
    reportTemplate: simpleReport.jrxml
    attributes:
      map: !map
        maxDpi: 400
        width: 780
        height: 330
    processors:
    - !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
      directory: '.'
    - !createMap
      inputMapper: {map: map}
      outputMapper: {mapSubReport: map}
    - !configureHttpRequests
          httpProcessors:
          - !restrictUris
            matchers:
            - !ipMatch
              ip: webapps.sit.puglia.it
```

I've made sure to allow the use of the server.

This is my **JSON request**:

```
{
    "attributes": {"map": {
        "bbox": [
            2251632.4276,
            4054757.3924,
            2835795.3321,
            5221314.5428 
        ],
        "dpi": 72,
        "layers": [{
            "baseURL": "http://webapps.sit.puglia.it/arcgis/services/Background/TNOInquadramento/MapServer/WMSServer",
            "customParams": {
                "EXCEPTIONS": "INIMAGE",
                "TRANSPARENT": "true"
            },
            "imageFormat": "image/png",
            "layers": ["Confini Provinciali"],
            "type": "WMS",
            "version": "1.3.0"
        }],
        "projection": "EPSG:3004",
        "rotation": 0
    }},
    "layout": "A4 landscape"
}
```

Actually using the layer's name I get the following error:

> Parameter 'layers' contains unacceptable layer names.

which I solved using the layer id.

So what's wrong with the first service? Is it some peculiarity of the service or is it my own Mapfish instance?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that I was requesting the wrong layer.

As stated in the question, for some reason Mapfish has problems loading the layer by its name so I had to find the layer by ID.

To do this I loaded the layer on ArcGIS and gathered its ID from ArcGIS description (right-click on the layer).

But apparently this description is relative to the rest ArcGIS server proprietary protocol, while I have to refer to the WMS capabilities.